# SwiftUI: Logout and switch screens from a popover

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-environment, swiftui-sheet, swiftui-toolbar

In my app, I have a View which is set to either a login View or a home TabView, depending on if the user is logged in. From the TabView, the user can go to a profile popover and logout. I want to switch back to the login View from this popover.

I tried dismissing the popover and immediately logging the user out, but when I test on a real device, what happens is the popover stays on the screen and also no longer responds to user input. It can't be dismissed. I'm not sure why, and what should I do instead?

Starting View:

```
struct StartView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var authService:AuthService
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if(!authService.signedIn) {
                LoginView()
            } else {
                HomeView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Home TabView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    @State private var showingProfilePopover:Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Tab 1")
                    .padding(.leading, 30)
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Button(action: {
                            showingProfilePopover = true
                            }, label: {
                                Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle").imageScale(.large)
                            }
                        )
                    }
                }
                
            }.popover(isPresented: $showingProfilePopover) {
                ProfileView(isPresented: $showingProfilePopover)
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "list.bullet")
                    .font(.system(size: 26))
                Text("Tab 1")
            }
            
            
            
            NavigationView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Tab 2")
                }
            }.tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "books.vertical")
                    .font(.system(size: 26))
                Text("Tab 2")
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Popover:

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var authService:AuthService
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Logout") {
            // Close the popup and switch to LoginView
            print("Tapped logout")
            isPresented = false
            
            authService.signOut()
        }
        .font(Font.custom("OpenSans-Regular", size: 18))
            .padding(20)
    }
}
```

---

LoginView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var authService:AuthService
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Login") {
                self.authService.signIn()
            }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
    }
}
```

AuthService:

```
import SwiftUI

class AuthService: ObservableObject {
    @Published var signedIn:Bool
    
    init(signedIn:Bool) {
        self.signedIn = signedIn
    }
    
    func signIn() {
        self.signedIn = true
    }
    
    func signOut(){
        self.signedIn = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like an issue connected to `.popover`. I can reproduce the issue, but it works just fine using `.sheet` instead.

Consider attaching the `.popover` on the `TabView` or the `Button` itself then it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the issue only happens on the older versions of iOS. it works fine on iOS 15, but not on iOS 14 and below iOS 14.

```
@main
struct LoginApp: App {
    let authService: AuthService
    
    init() {
        authService = AuthService(signedIn: false)
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            StartView().environmentObject(authService)
        }
    }
}
```

This is iPhone 8, iOS 14

[image]

Comment: I used iOS 14 on an iPhone 12

Comment: I also saw the issue of the popover not dismissing on a simulator with iOS 15.2

Comment: yeah, at first I thought it was the concurrency issue. Looks like Hallo gave you a working solution